# Do a dynamic django ORM filter by passing a string key,value pair

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to do the following in the django ORM:

```
field = 'name'
value = 'patrick'
Asset.objects.filter(field=value)
```

On a one-off basis I could do:

```
a = Asset()
a.setattr(field, name)
a.save()
```

But this would take too long for my purposes.

Is this possible to using the `object`, as I have about 50k items to update based on an enumerate field/value that's provided by the user.

One other way to say it would be how to emulate this pattern, or do I have to write raw sql for this, i.e., `"SELECT * FROM asset WHERE %s='%s' % (field, value)` (Note I now that expression is prone to SQL-injection, but that is fine -- this is trusted (enumerated) input values).

```
>>> Asset.objects.filter('name'='patrick')
  File "<console>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: i'm sorry can you explain more what you want to achieve, what problem(s) are you having, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword Arguments can be used in your case.

> - keyword argument: an argument preceded by an identifier (e.g. name=) in a function call or passed as a value in a dictionary preceded by **. For example, 3 and 5 are both keyword arguments in the following calls to complex():

```
complex(real=3, imag=5)
complex(**{'real': 3, 'imag': 5})
```

In your case, it will look like this.

```
key = input()
value = input()

kwargs = {
    '{0}'.format(key): '{0}'.format(value),
}

Asset.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

You can also add for loop etc, whatsoever this answers your question, hope this solves your problem.